# Delayed job: uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am trying to save pdfs using delayed job. Here is what  have done so far.

gemfile

```
gem 'delayed_job', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.3'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.2'
gem "daemons"
```

Then run commands

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

config/application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

initializers/delayed_job_config.rb

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 60
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 10
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 10
Delayed::Worker.default_queue_name = 'default'
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'delayed_job.log'))
```

then in controller

```
def save_file
 @articles = Article.all
 @articles.each do |article|
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(SaveArticle.new(article.id))
 end
end
```

and SaveArticle.rb

```
class SaveArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  def perform(article_id)
    pdf = GeneratePdf.new(article_id)
    pdf.render_file(article_id.to_s + ".pdf")
  end
end
```

This gives me error

```
uninitialized constant MyController::GeneratePdf
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, where's your `GeneratePdf` thing?

Comment: Its a big class that generates the pdf and it is in the same directory as SaveArticle.rb

Comment: try with `::GeneratePdf.new(article_id)`